# Saving imageViews programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, save, android-linearlayout

I have 3 horizontal linear layouts in which I'm adding imageviews programmatically. When I close the app and reopen it, it doesn't save the image views that I've added. How can I save this imageviews and reload them on resume?

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Chickens"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Chickens"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cows"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Cows"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Horses"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Horses"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

In Activity :

```
Chickens = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Chickens);
Cows = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Cows);
Horses = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Horses);

ImageView houseForChickens = new ImageView(this);
houseForChickens.setImageResource(R.drawable.house);
Chickens.addView(houseForChickens, 300, 300);
```

Comment: save the imageview? you mean the src? how did you get the image, from webservice? or locally. If from webservice, you can save the link in database or sharepreferences. If you get it from drawerable (local), you don't need to save, you can just load it again.

Comment: The imageview is added from drawable:ImageView houseForChickens  = new ImageView(this);
        houseForChickens.setImageResource(R.drawable.house);) and then I'm adding it in layout (Chickens.addView(houseForChickens,300,300);), how can I reload it? I'm a beginner..

Comment: since you said you close the app and reopen it. So the app restarts and it will run the loading of the imageView again. If your app uses fragment. When the fragment loads, it will load the image as well. Maybe u show me your .xml file where your image located. And how you call this xml.

Comment: add an answer below. Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your xlm

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_houseForChickens  "
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/R.drawable.house"/>
```

In code

```
ImageView houseForChickens  = (ImageView ) findViewById(R.id.iv_houseForChickens  );
```

see if you want to set the src in code or put in xlm , up to you

Comment: It didn't work, but thank you anyway! I'm adding new "houses" in the layout with a button and if I press it now after what you told me, it doesn't work. Maybe it's my fault, I will see if I can fix it. Happy coding too :)